# MainActivity lost context after passing context to non-activity class

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-context

I am working on a simple program - and actually face a problem which I can not solve. Hope that anyone out here can help me.

Programming Intend:

=> I pass a `Context` from `MainActivity` to a non-activity class by constructor
   argument.

=> non-activity class works fine - the `AssetManager` finds the files to be read
   from /src/assets and reads them in

=> but once the `MainActivity` is to display the activity - it crashes

The code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("dtd_smartshopper.dtd",this.getApplicationContext());
    }
}
}


public class FileReader {
public FileReader(String fn, Context con) {
    String line = null;
    try {
        AssetManager am = con.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open(fn);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("FileReader",line);
        }
        am.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("onBtnOkClick","IOException: " + e);
    }
}

}
```

Stack trace is:

```
06-04 12:38:54.222: I/FileReader(330): <!-- End of SmartShopper DTD Master File -->
06-04 12:38:54.313: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
06-04 12:38:54.313: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/abc_action_menu_layout.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f030009
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1916)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1871)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:72)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:151)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setMenu(ActionBarView.java:428)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:609)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:421)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:230)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assetmanager has been closed
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:483)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1898)
06-04 12:38:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 18 more
```

I guess it might be a small problem - hope you can help me!

Comment: Can you post the **full** stacktrace please?

Comment: Avoid using Activity Context in long running operations. Use Application Context instead.

Comment: thy - but the problem remains.... no matter if I use application context (as I did in my example?)!

Comment: Log trace says there is no file named res/layout/abc_action_menu_layout.xml

Answer (score 1):

1. Please don't read files from UI thread.
2. In order to fix crash just don't close `AssetManager` (that's why you app crashes).

You don't this need line:

```
am.close();
```

You need to close `BufferedReader` instead:

```
in.close();
```